# Java EE 6 SDK uninstall 'Could not find the required version of the Java(TM) 2 Runtime Environment'

Tags: null, uninstallation, java

I want to uninstall my Java EE 6 SDK on my windows 7 machine, but when I run the included uninstall program, I get the following error.

```
Error: Could not find the required version of the Java(TM) 2 Runtime Environment in'(null)'.
```

Followed by...

```
This application needs version 1.6 or higher of the Java(TM) 2 Runtime Environment
```

How to fix this? Do i have to install the java 2 runtime environment just to uninstall my Java EE 6 SDK?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

That's right. You need to install Java SE from http://www.java.com in order to be able to run the Java EE (un)installer. It's written in Java, so it needs at least a JVM.

Comment: sorry for this nweb question, but where would I get a JVM? I only see Java 6 version 24 for download and not the JVM... thanks!!!!

Comment: The JVM is the execution platform.  One is included in all downloadable versions of Java from Oracle.

Comment: JVM (Java Virtual Machine, it's the one responsible for running Java code) is part of Java SE download. Just go to the java.com link and follow the instructions.

Answer (score 25):

Make sure you have both the 32 and 64 bits version of JRE installed. 
The Java EE x64 installer won't work without the 32 bits JRE installation.

Comment: A 32-bit JRE is not required. If you have the 64-bit JRE, simply add the `-j` command line argument with the path to your JRE, as shown by @Madhan.

Answer (score 25):

I got the same problem. By installing the program with following parameters it worked like charm.

```
java_ee_sdk-6u4-jdk7-windows-x64.exe -j "D:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_06"
```

where D:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_06 is the folder I have installed JDK 7 in my system.

Comment: +1 This is the perfect solution, no need to have Java SDK just a JRE will do

Answer (score 4):

So assuming you're uninstalling from the uninstaller in the glassfish directory. You can specify the uninstaller with your JAVA_HOME environment variable in the command line:

```
uninstall.exe -j "%JAVA_HOME%"
```

Comment: I've tried everything above, and finally this worked! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

I have got all these problems and more, and I found something really simple. All that you have to do is erase Eclipse, go to Eclipse and download the 32-bit Galileo; that works pretty good. You don't need to copy to change a path or anything else.

Answer (score 1):

Do this:

```
uninstall.exe -j "C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre"
```

Answer (score 0):

I installed the JRE 7 u 45 for Windows 7 (x64 version), then was able to install the 64-bit version of Java EE 7 (x64 version) by using the command line below. Just update the j parameter to point to the java runtime directory on your system:

```
c:\temp> java_ee_sdk-7-jdk7-windows-x64.exe -j "C:\Program Files\Java\jre7"
```

Answer (score 0):

I had uninstalled both 32-bit Java (C:\Program Files (x86)\Java...) and 64-bit(C:\Program Files\Java...), but for some reason it left behind a java folder (C:\Program Files\Java...).
ONce I manually deleted that folder, the error went away.

Answer (score 0):

I have encountered the same problem while installing JAVA EE SDK 7. Setting `PATH`, `CLASS_PATH`, `JAVA_HOME` variables solved the issue.